# Android Studio 2.3 - Cannot lock System Folders

Tags: android, locking, port

I'm new to Android App Development and am using Android Studio 2.3 to learn it. I've been working on it for a week now but now I'm getting the following error:

[port lock error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFZ9p.png)

Currently I'm working on a project so I need this error to be resolved.
Please help.

Comment: looks like you have to reinstall Android Studio. It's directories got corrupted.

Comment: I'll try that. Is there anyway I can do that without having to redownload the SDK and all?

Answer (score 0):

its problem with androidstudio.exe download from here [its official site to download studio.](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

if any query after install new studio ask me.

Comment: I have installed Android Studio from that site only and it was working fine until yesterday

Comment: than problem with your drive try to install in other drive.

Answer (score 0):

try this my friend

1. Go to folder where android-studio is installed. (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio)
2. Now go one folder back. (i.e. C:\Program Files (x86)\Android)
3. Right click on the android-studio folder and click to **Properties.**
4. Once in the **Properties window**, go to the **Security** tab.
5. Click the **Edit** button
6. In the new window that opens up click the **Users** (your-username-or-your-group-name)
7. From the list below, check **Allow** in front of **Full control**.
8. Press **OK**, then again **OK**.
   I hope it help you!

for more information [follow this link](https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-resolve-android-studios-cannot-lock-system-folders-error-in-windows-7-32-bit)

Comment: I have tried this but I am still getting the same error. Please advise